# java.util.Set conversion to scala.immutable.Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `Set[Set[String], Set[String]]` of java.util.Set type which I want to convert to `scala.immutable.Map[String, scala.immutable.Set[String]]`. The mapping is like each element of the first set inside the outermost set maps to the second set of the outermost set. I tried a for expression:

```
for (groupRole <- groupRoleAccess;
     user <- groupService.getGroup(groupRole.groupId).getUsers.asScala;
     permissions = roleService.getRole(groupRole.roleId).getPermissions.asScala)
  yield Map(user, permissions)
```

where `groupRoleAccess` is the outermost set,

`getUsers` gives me the first set inside the outermost set,

`getPermissions` gives me the second set inside the outermost set

However, what I get is a `Set[Map[String, Set[String]]]` and of the `collection.mutable.Set` type. Do I again apply a function to change this Set to the Map I need or is there a better way out?

Comment: Could you please give an example, i.e. from the Scala REPL, of a value having type `Set[Set[String], Set[String]]`? Also, can you please an example of `desiredFunction(input example) === desiredOutput`? Example: `addOne(4) === 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your `yield` to `yield user -> permissions`.
That will give you a `Set[(String, Set[String])]`. You then do `.toMap` on it, and voila!

Alternatively (I am not recommending this, but just for the sake of completeness), you can just do `.reduce(_ ++ _)` on the result of what you have. That'll merge your set of maps into one map. 
(Note, if there is a possibility, that the result is going to be empty, you'll want `foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Set[String]]){ _ ++  _ }` instead of `reduce`).

Answer (score 0):

Right now what you are doing is collecting `Map[String, Set[String]]` which the for loop adds to a set.

One way to accomplish what you want to do is to output the results of the for loop into a tuple and then use the toMap function

```
val x = for( user <- ...; permissions <- ...) yield (user, permissions) 
x.toMap
```